# MVC controller start reading payload before complete

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5, xmlreader

Apologies I can’t paste any code at present but I want to get this down while it’s in my head.

I have an asp.net mvc intRAnet business application with knockout js running in the browser. This posts data to an mvc controller method via an Ajax call. My problem is, the data it’s posting can be very large. On clicking the submit button, it can take up to 10 minutes before a break point on the first line of the controller method is hit. Functionally, all is good but I need a way to reduce this delay. I was wondering if it may be possible for the controller method to read the posted data in a streaming fashion, ie so that it may begin processing before the fully payload had been posted from the browser.

The data posted is xml so maybe I could use an xmlreader over the stream?

Hopefully this is a problem that’s already been solved by some framework tweak but I’m really open to suggestions.

Comment: how big is the data, is it a file or form data

Comment: It's an array of json objects or order data. Each object has 6 columns of text. These are presented to the user in a grid (using KOGrid) that allows them to page through and edit where necessary. Most orders contain only a couple of dozen lines but some orders can contain everal thousand lines. There's no performance problem in presenting and paging through the data (I'm using entity framework take / skip), the problem comes when making the ajax call to submit the edited order to the controller

Comment: the above sound sounds gd, i would need to understand why the payload is so big if you are using paging, sounds like your not just storing and sending the changed records... we would need to see code at this point.